# Permalinks for WordPress Custom Post Types Not Working

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting

I've set 2 custom post type, let's refer to them as type1 and type2. Both will have post with same names so the only difference between them is their type and content. For example there will be 2 posts with same title "Title1" which will have permalinks
http://domain.com/type1/title1 and http://domain.com/type2/title1.
Here I've encountered weird problem. 1st link works just fine, 2nd one for some weird reason redirects to 1st one. What can be causing this and how to fix it?

Comment: it seems guid is set to http://domain.com?post_type=type2&#038;p=postidhere instead of http://domain.com/type2/title1. I wonder why

Comment: I've noticed that occasionally when I'm adding new taxonomies and post types, that going to Settings > Permalinks and clicking "Save Changes" will force the permalink rewrite rules to be flushed and things will start working as I expect them to.

Comment: read that, tried that. apparently, it didn't help =/

Comment: Another thing to try is putting a call to `flush_rewrite_rules()` in your functions.php file.

Comment: Are you sure you've got everything in your `register_post_type` calls correct? Specifically the `rewrite` label?

Comment: well, register_post_type is same as of type1 except things that should be different like label and post type. rewrite is not set in call and is defaults to true.

Comment: also, even though i took away call to register second custom type ( i figured i don't need it) it still redirects to type1 =/